# C# MF4.2 How to pause a program using an emergency switch button?

Tags: c#, pause

I am starting to build a program for a Netduino 1 controller to monitor temperature sensors to control heating elements. In case of an emergency I want the user to be able to pause the system by pressing a emergency stop button. When the problem is resolved the user will reset the emergency button which would resume the program execution. What would be the strategy to adopt?

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Sounds like you know exactly what to do - push a button to stop monitoring, push it again to start. You can even put a physical switch on the data line - voila! - no signals to monitor.

Comment: Well, I see I am not specific enough. I am looking for a mean to manage this scenario in C#.

Comment: That's still far from enough info. How about a timer? Is that enough info?